# mySQL stored procedure not giving me error messages

Tags: mysql

The following stored procedure works as intended BUT if I force an error (see intentional type-o in INSERT statement) I don't get any error information.

I created a table called error_check and tried inserting error info into there to see if I could get some more information, but when there is an error, no rows are added to the table.  (When I take out the type-o, I get a new row with nulls in it, as expected.)

This used to work, so I'm sure it is something I added by mistake.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `addClassToMasterList`( IN begin_date VARCHAR(10), IN day_num INT,
                               IN startTime VARCHAR(10), IN endTime VARCHAR (20), IN loc_id INT, IN studio VARCHAR(20),
                               IN class_name VARCHAR(45), IN owner_id INT,
                               IN club_id INT, OUT return_id VARCHAR(250))
BEGIN

DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION, NOT FOUND, SQLWARNING
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK;  
    GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1 @sqlstate = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, 
                                @errno = MYSQL_ERRNO, 
                                @text = MESSAGE_TEXT;
    SET @display_error = CONCAT("ERROR ", @errno, " (", @sqlstate, "): ", @text);
END;   /*end of exception handing*/

SET @formatted_date = STR_TO_DATE(begin_date, '%m/%d/%Y');

/* Save all data as a new row in the Master Schedule */
INSERT INTO master_class_list_typeo_here
VALUES (null, 
    day_num, 
    @formatted_date, 
    null,
    startTime, 
    endTime, 
    loc_id, 
    studio,
    class_name, 
    owner_id, 
    club_id); 

SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO @new_id;

/* Put bits of error into a table so I can see what is going on. */
INSERT INTO error_check
VALUES (null, @display_error, @text, @errno);

/* If an error message was generated, return the error.
   Otherwise, return the new id that was automatically created. */
SELECT IF (@display_error, @display_error, @new_id) INTO return_id;
/* Also tried:  SELECT @display_error INTO return_id;  */

END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```sql
...
GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1
...
```

> [13.6.7.3 GET DIAGNOSTICS Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/get-diagnostics.html)
>
> ...
>
> The keyword STACKED means to retrieve information from the second
>   diagnostics area, which is available only if the current context is a
>   condition handler.
>
> ...

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jX6mPaBJv8uozbgwQTUKEh/1).

Comment: I believe you may have it, but mySQL Workspace is giving me a syntax error about the word "STACKED".   Will keep investigating and get back.

Comment: @B.Krafft: What version of MySQL are you using?.

Comment: I'm using MySQL 5.6 and Workbench 6.3

Comment: A HA!  I just checked the 5.6 documentation and it does NOT include "stacked" as an option for GET DIAGNOSTICS.  Will try to up grade (gulp) and that should do it.

Comment: @B.Krafft: In version 5.6, I get the desired result, without `STACKED`, see [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jX6mPaBJv8uozbgwQTUKEh/2).

Comment: Well, I don't know where I went wrong, but I started with your db_fiddle and build everything all over again and now it is working.  So I think you for that!

Answer (score 0):

Place your `INSERT INTO error_check` statement within the `BEGIN...END` logical block of your exception handling, using `INSERT INTO... SELECT...` like so:

```sql
...
BEGIN
    -- ROLLBACK;  
    GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1 @sqlstate = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, 
                                @errno = MYSQL_ERRNO, 
                                @text = MESSAGE_TEXT;
    SET @display_error = CONCAT("ERROR ", @errno, " (", @sqlstate, "): ", @text);

    /* Put bits of error into a table so I can see what is going on. */
    INSERT INTO error_check
    SELECT null, @display_error, @text, @errno;

END;   /*end of exception handing*/
...
```

This works for me. Note that I also commented out the `ROLLBACK`